# Spring Data Neo4j 4 Repository method returns 1 element

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm moving from SDN 3 to SDN 4 and from Neo4j 2.3 to 3.0.1

On new dependencies my test fails with an assertion. Instead of 3 nodes it returns only one.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Decision extends Commentable {

    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";
    private final static String DEFINED_BY = "DEFINED_BY";
    private final static String VOTED_FOR = "VOTED_FOR";

    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = DEFINED_BY, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<Criterion> criteria = new HashSet<>();

....


@NodeEntity
public class Criterion extends Authorable {

    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";
    private final static String DEFINED_BY = "DEFINED_BY";

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private CriterionGroup group;

    @Relationship(type = DEFINED_BY, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Decision owner;


@Test
    public void testGetChildDecisionsSortedBySumOfCriteriaAvgVotesWeightWithCoefficients() {
        User user = userService.createUser("test", "test", "test@test.com", null, null);

        final Decision rootDecision1 = decisionDao.create("Root decision1", "Root decision 1 description", null, user);

        final Criterion rootDecision1Criterion1 = criterionDao.create("rootDecision1Criterion1", "rootDecision1Criterion1", rootDecision1, user);
        final Criterion rootDecision1Criterion2 = criterionDao.create("rootDecision1Criterion2", "rootDecision1Criterion2", rootDecision1, user);
        final Criterion rootDecision1Criterion3 = criterionDao.create("rootDecision1Criterion3", "rootDecision1Criterion3", rootDecision1, user);

        assertEquals(3, criterionDao.getCriteriaDefinedByDecision(rootDecision1.getId()).size());
```

Repository method:

```
@Query("MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c:Criterion) WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} RETURN c")
List<Criterion> getCriteriaDefinedByDecision(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId);
```

What can be a reason of this issue and how to fix it ?

**UPDATED**

I found that construction

```
public Criterion(String name, String description, Decision owner, User author) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.owner = owner;
        setAuthor(author);
    }
```

is not enough for SDN 4 in order to create ONE_TO_MANY association.. I have to add additional lines in order to add object to parent collection also.

```
public Criterion(String name, String description, Decision owner, User author) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.owner = owner;
        if (owner != null) {
            owner.addCriterion(this);
        }
        setAuthor(author);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem , try removing  `DEFINED_BY @Relationship` from `Criterion`

```
   @NodeEntity
   public class Criterion extends Authorable {

    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";
    private final static String DEFINED_BY = "DEFINED_BY";

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private CriterionGroup group;


}
```

Create `Criterion` first and then connect them to `Decision`

Comment: Thanks, but I need this field in accordance with my application business logic. It worked perfectly in the previous version of SDN.. why did they change this ?

Comment: Don't know , have the same problem .